# Stop SVG images colliding

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, smil

I need to animate some "swirl" sprites to create an animation that looks like a wind effect. Remit is:

> "Please keep in mind that wind swirls need to be placed randomly and
>   do not overlap each other."

I have the original code which contains various different transforms from the code libraries *[animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate)* by *Daniel Eden* and *[Glide](https://github.com/nickpettit/glide)* by *Nick Pettit*. I don't think much would be gained by reproducing all the code, but at present there are a bunch of different transforms and such which combine to give a fairly pleasing semi-random slide and 'smooth-judder', but do, unfortunately, often overlap.

Sample from animate.css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
  [...]
  90% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
}
```

And from Glide:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  [...] 

  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

Anyway, you get the general idea. The issue I'm having is I don't understand how to define an edge on these images, and to do so in such a way as to stop them from overlapping each other when they collide (or even better, to have a 'soft-buffer' or border of a few millimeters around them, into which other swirl sprites will not enter). I have tried Googling:

[Stop images overlapping in CSS](http://google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=stop%20images%20overlapping%20in%20CSS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=eIt3WKHkO4L38Afa66GgAw)

and

[Stop SVG images overlapping](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=stop+images+svg+images+overlapping)

But all of these seem to concern normal css flow and/or objects overlapping on different screen sizes, or on screen resize, rather than transforms of the kind I'm attempting. **Could anyone give me the gist of how to ensure some sort of 'collision box' type thing around the SVG sprites**, or even better point me towards a code library that already does this?

I don't need hand-holding on this one, but just an idea of where to start would be great. Of course if people want to provide the code that's even better, but I'd just like to know if there's anything pre-written, or if not, what angle you'd suggest approaching the task from.

I'm not averse to using JavaScript if need be, or maybe other web coding languages (I can't do C++ yet, but Python would be ok, ditto Go Lang, though I'd rather avoid these if possible -- also, maybe there's something that can be done on it in SMIL?); and there's already a jQuery library being called within the code, though I don't *recall* any jQuery functions likely to work here.

Comment: Sounds like you are after a physics simulation library.  Try typing "Javascript physics engine" into your favourite search engine.

But are you sure your interpretaion of your instructions is correct?  It sounds to me like the requester would be happy with just some objects following predefined non-overlapping motion paths.

Comment: If the swirls were to be genuinely randomly placed, as per the specification, there would be no way to implement these 'predefined non-overlapping routes' without some sort of collision detection. At least, no way I know of.

Comment: There is a difference between swirls randomly generated at run time, and and predefined ones that appear to be random.  It isn't clear, from the one sentence you quoted, which was desired.

Comment: No. And the deadline for completion of the task has finished. I am now working on a psyops Twitter bot for a client named Alisa Shevchenko ( http://twitter.com/bravebot1984 ). But thanks for the input. Feel free to join in the competition if you are inclined.